# Hiding the quoted messages in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

In the Mail application, when I choose the option "see more from " the app unfolds the replied messages in different colors as quoted texts. How can we undo the unfolding and hide the quoted text? It is so messy right now.

Please see the image below for the part that I want to hide.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to hide the vertical lines, not recollapse the whole reply chain? AFAIK that's not possible.

Comment: Preferences in the Mail Application on a Macbook lets you choose to have this display in this way or not.

Comment: can you tell me which one it is? I looked around but couldn't see.

Comment: mail app/ preferences / viewing / uncheck "Include related messages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the list of mails, change the mail and come back to the previous one. It automatically folds all the quotes, when you revisit it.

Comment: I chose different mails from the LHS, but didn't work. Still unfolded.

Comment: This is what I just did. Opened message 2 (for say )by single clicking message 2 from the list. Single clicked message 1. Single clicked message 2. Bingo!  I think you might be opening it by double clicking in order to open it as a new window.

Comment: This is for inbox. If you’re talking about what to do while replying or drafting a new message, I recommend saving the draft and opening it again from the draft tab to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: I understand what you mean. It works for some cases, but not all the time. I will observe more to understand the difference. Thank you.

Comment: not sure why accepted as a solution, clearly does not work

Answer (score -2):

You can choose to make them white. Open Mail from your Dock, then next to the Apple icon upper left corner click Mail, preferences, Fonts and Colors tab, uncheck color or make them white.